# Is it possible for azure custom vision api to detect multiple objects in single image

Tags: computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-custom-vision

I am new to Azure Cognitive services. I want to detect multiple objects in a single image. Is it possible with custom vision api.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to with the Object Detection part of Custom Vision. Simply give it images of multiples to train on and it should start detecting both items.

For example, I was playing with it a while ago to see if it could detect red and white wines. After sending a few images with both to train on I started getting results like the below.

[image]

Comment: Hello, any idea about how many classes(objects) is the pre-trained model that is provided on the site where you can upload an image have. how many objects is it trained on and what are they? and can I add more classes to them. I read in the documentations that there thousands of classes. Is there more documentation about what the classes are?